# Difference between useSession and getSession in next-auth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

What's the difference between `useSession` and `getSession` in `next-auth`? Both  seems to be returning `session` object.

Comment: For a more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77093615/difference-between-usesession-getsession-and-getserversession-in-next-auth/77094871#77094871

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`useSession` ReactJS hook that works only on client, that returns states which helps you to update UI and it's made on top of `getSession`

`getSession` async function that read current cookies and returns session, works both on Client and Server

Comment: And what about `getSession` vs `getServerSession` ?

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen you can protect server side rendered pages using the getServerSession method. This is different from the old getSession() method, in that it does not do an extra fetch out over the internet to confirm data from itself, increasing performance significantly.

You need to add this to every server rendered page you want to protect. Be aware, getServerSession takes slightly different arguments than the method it is replacing, getSession.

Check this [link](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes)

Comment: For a more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77093615/difference-between-usesession-getsession-and-getserversession-in-next-auth/77094871#77094871